# AWS: Process all data from S3 input bucket to S3 output bucket with executable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have the following use case:

On an S3 input bucket, I have a large number of log files (e.g. 5 TB across 100K objects). I need to process these log files using a custom executable that transforms the log files to another format - and then I wish to write the result to an output S3 bucket.

This is simple enough to do file-by-file via AWS Lambda for newly added log files. I could also run a Lambda function on all the individual log files in my input bucket to get a single output file for each input.

However, my executable is also able to concatenate the input log files together in chunks of X MB. On a regular PC, this would be achieved by providing the executable with an input folder containing all the files.

However, in AWS I am not sure how to achieve the equivalent. In e.g. an AWS Glue Job or similar, it seems I would need to download all 5 TB to some temporary directory - which is of course not possible/practical. Alternatively, I would need some method to 'map' the input bucket as a local drive - but s3fs is e.g. not a practical solution in this case either, as my executable is going to be run via a `subprocess.run` statement, i.e. it won't be possible to parse an fsspec object to it unless it's directly mapped to the operating system.

Is there a way to achieve this within e.g. AWS Glue Jobs or other serverless services in the AWS environment?

Answer (score 0):

For long running jobs I've used AWS Batch. With the right permissions you can access the S3 buckets for reading and writing as well as other AWS resources. In my case, I had a .Net Core executable that was passed parameters. Using the parameters, I accessed the S3 objects for processing and then moved to another S3 location.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html

Comment: Thanks! I’ve been leaning towards lambda to ensure the setup is serverless to avoid any EC2s running continuously. Lambda will be fine for all “new” file uploads so I’m mainly looking for a simple way to handle “backlogs” of data. Is it possible to set up AWS Batch in a serverless way?

Comment: You can use AWS Batch with Fargate and not have to worry about EC2 instances. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/fargate.html

Answer (score 0):

S3 Batch Operations with Lambda may be a good option here. You'd just write a lambda function and then either provide a filter or list of objects and then S3 Batch Operations will invoke the lambda on every object and provide a report on the results. See the following links for more details

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-s3-batch.html\](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-s3-batch.html%5C)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-invoke-lambda.html